# OpenFL stage how to force __focusObject to another element

Tags: javascript, haxe, stage, openfl

I am trying to get keyboard events to work by using

```
Lib.current.stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, dispatchKeyEvent, false, 0, true );
Lib.current.stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, dispatchKeyEvent, false, 0, true );
```

The events fire but the stage's `__focusObject` is still my preloader. At this point it no longer exists and only the game is visible.

The events propagate to my game once I click the screen changing the stage's `focusObject` to my game. But prior to clicking the game element the events only propagate through my preloader.

Is there a way to force the focus to the game without having to physically click it?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the focus of the `Stage` like this:

```js
stage.focus = null;
```

That should make keyboard events dispatch from the `Stage` instead of another focused object.

The latest versions of OpenFL should remove focus automatically when unloading the preloader. If this does not appear to be the case, please report an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/issues) with sample code.

Comment: We are on an extremely old version and at this moment are unable to upgrade... >.< lol...

I will give that a try though thanks!

Comment: Making it null does not seem to work.

Stage.hx:597 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__fireEvent' of null

Comment: What version of OpenFL are you using? Is there an additional flag you use to compile (such as `-D legacy`)?

Comment: We are on 1.4.0. I know... I have zero stake in this decision. Anyways would -D legacy work that far back as I am pretty sure our Haxe version is super outdated as well.

Comment: IF you could point out the fix that was made for this it may be possible for me to fork 1.4.0 and apply it myself if the fix is even compatible with this version

Comment: Would you mind letting me know if there are any reasons for using an older version, that might be worse in a newer version? Knowing would help. Is this HTML5? If so, writing `@:privateAccess stage.__focus = null;` might work

Comment: We have an entire game framework built on top of openfl that uses tons of depreciated openfl and haxe code. They do not want to spend the time upgrading it.

Comment: Try Lib.current.stage.focus = Lib.current.stage;

Comment: All these cause compile errors but thanks for the suggested help!! I found that if before disposing of my preloader if I add it as a child of my game then the events will propagate through the rest of the children